# Prevent users from liking a photo multiple times

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django project and I am using tastypie to turn my app into a REST based API.

I let users upload photographs and then other registered users can like them. I want to prevent a single from liking a photo more than once.

I know that using views or tastypie specific code I could add functionality to check if a user has already like a photograph and if they have then not increment the count. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this check within the model (and if that is good or bad)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you have a model for likes? If not, create it as an [intermediary model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for M2M User <-> Photo relation. Next, add a simple [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
unique_together = ("user", "photo")
```

It's enforced on the database level, so it will give you good performance.

If you don't want a dedicated model for keeping likes, unfortunately I cannot help – there is no other elegant way of saving a fact that some user liked some photo. At the end you should be happy with M2M because of extra features you can easily add afterwards: unlike photos, show who liked a particular photo, when the most likes occurred, add a degree of "liking" and so on.

Good luck!